# Не получается реализовать навигацию Fragment-ов

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction, fragment-manager

Хочу реализовать переход меджу фрагментами на активити. Для этого реализовал вот такую логику переходов:

```
public class FragmentViewer {

private MainActivity activity;
private BaseFragment defaultFragment;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

public FragmentViewer(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    defaultFragment = new NewWordFragment();
    showDefaultFragment();
}

private void showDefaultFragment() {
    fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, defaultFragment, defaultFragment.getFragmentTag())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

public void showFragment(BaseFragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if(!isUsedFragment(fragment, activity.getSupportFragmentManager())) {
        fragmentTransaction
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, fragment.getFragmentTag())
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getFragmentTag())
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else if(!isTopPosition(fragment, activity.getSupportFragmentManager())){
        fragmentTransaction
                .remove(fragment)
                .commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, fragment.getFragmentTag())
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getFragmentTag())
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}

private boolean isTopPosition(BaseFragment fragment, FragmentManager fm) {
    return fm.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getFragmentTag()).isResumed();
}

private boolean isUsedFragment(BaseFragment fragment, FragmentManager fm){
    Fragment newFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getFragmentTag());
    return newFragment != null;
}

}
```

И вот когда я открыл фраграмент 1 (дефолтно), открываю другой фрагмент 2 - все отлично, когда вызываю фрагмент 1 - он показывается сверху (только они накладываются), а мне нужно проверить есть ли такой и если есть, то поставить его наверх. Но `.show()` не работает.

Comment: чтобы не накладывались, нужно использовать место метода add() метод replace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в методе `isTopPosition` - он всегда возвращает `true`.

Нужно изменить реализацию метода, если используете `return`:

```
((BaseUserFragment)fm.getFragments().get(fm.getFragments().size()-1)).getFragmentTag().equals(fragment.getFragmentTag());
```